# Automated Spoofing of MAC address on macOS

Tags: linux, bash, macos, mac-address

I am trying to build an automated program that does the following sequences on macOS to spoof the mac address.

1. Disconnect from any wifi networks
2. Change mac address
3. Reconnect to the wifi network

The problem is, in order to change the wifi address on macOS, the wifi module must be on but disconnected from any networks meaning `networksetup -setairportpower en0 off` and `sudo ifconfig en0 down` will not work. In addition turning on the network service will not work either: `sudo networksetup -setnetworkserviceenabled Wi-Fi off`.

Theoretically, I have considered deleting the network history file, creating a backup, changing what I need, and then putting it back. The problem with this is that it wouldn't work with ethernet. Unless I am mistaken?

For reference, the command I am using to change the MAC address is:

```
openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//' | xargs sudo ifconfig en0 ether
```

Are there any libraries or commands I could use to disconnect from the current network other than going to the menu bar and clicking disconnect?

Comment: Try something like macchanger. Not sure if there's a MacOS version, but I found https://github.com/acrogenesis/macchanger

Comment: Try `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.framework/Versions/Current/Resources/airport --disassociate` and see if that does what you need.

Comment: I think those are both useful solutions. I forgot about the AirPort command. Thanks for recommending.

Comment: @HarrisonG If you got it working, you should write up an answer explaining how you solved it.

Comment: I might once I do further investigation. I am still building my solution.